# Would an Imp be resistant to the bludgeoning damage from a Mace of Warning?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage-resistance

The Damage Resistances for a 5E Imp are:

> Cold; Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks that aren't Silvered

Would this Imp be resistant to damage from a Mace of Warning?

- You could argue "Yes" because any Weapon of Warning should be considered a magical weapon, and therefore the damage it deals is considered magical.
- You could argue "No", with a liberal interpretation of the resistances, because the mace is not silvered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A Mace of Warning is a magical weapon that deals magical damage.

From the description of [Weapons of Warning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weapon-of-warning):

> This magic weapon...

Since it is a magic weapon, it deals magical damage, as the *Monster Manual* says in the section on [Vulnerabilities, Resistances, and Immunities](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#VulnerabilitiesResistancesandImmunities):

> a magical attack is an attack delivered by a spell, *a magic item*, or another magical source

Therefore, the Imp would not be resistant to damage from the Mace of Warning since it deals magical bludgeoning damage and the Imp has resistance to non-silvered, non-magical bludgeoning.